# Show polynomial is a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, holder-spaces

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded set and $p$ is a polynomial, then show that $p:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is a Lipschitz function.

Comment: People usually call this Locally Lipshitz.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have
$$x^k-y^k=(x-y)\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x^iy^{k-1-i}$$
and $A$ is bounded then there's $M>0$ such that
$$\forall x\in A\quad |x|\leq M$$
hence
$$|x^k-y^k|\leq|x-y|k M^{k-1}$$
then if 
$$P(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$
we have 
$$|P(x)-P(y)|\leq \sum_{k=1}^n|a_k||x^k-y^k|\leq|x-y|\sum_{k=1}^nk|a_k| M^{k-1}=C|x-y|$$

Comment: Thank you. Very, very helpful. I see it now

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 12):

Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$-function, i.e., $f'$ exists at every point and is continuous.   Since $f': [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, it is bounded: there is a constant $M$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.  By the Mean Value Theorem, for any $a \leq x \leq y \leq b$,

$|f(y)-f(x)| = |f'(c)||y-x| \leq M|y-x|$,

so $M$ is a Lipschitz constant for $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Finally, note that all polynomials are $C^1$ (indeed infinitely differentiable) on any interval and that any bounded set is contained in a closed, bounded interval.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n$. Calculate $P'(x)$. Using the Triangle Inequality, we find that
$$|P'(x)|\le n|a_0||x|^{n-1}+(n-1)|a_1||x|^{n-2} +\cdots +|a_n|.$$

Now use the fact that there is a $B$ such that $|x|\le B$.

Answer (score 3):

We can write $P(x)-P(y)=(x-y)Q(x,y)$ for some bivariate polynomial $Q$ (because we can do so at least when $P$ is a monomial).
As continuous function, $|Q(x,y)|$ is bounded on the compact set $A\times A$, by $L$ say. Then $L$ is a Lipschitz constant for $P$.

Answer (score 2):

- It's enough to show that $x\mapsto x^p$ is Lipschitz for any integer $p\geqslant 1$.
- Use the identity 
  $$x^p-y^p=(x-y)\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}x^jy^{p-1-j},$$
  and show that $\left|\sum_{j=0}^{p-1}x^jy^{p-1-j}\right|$ can be bounded independently of $x$ and  $y$.

Comment: Thank you but I am having trouble coming up with the bound for the summation. Thanks.

Comment: Triangular inequality plus the fact that we can find some $R>0$ such that $|t|\leqslant R$ for any $t\in A$ (by boundedness).