# Can I find a lipschitz constant for this term?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, radicals, lipschitz-functions

> I have given two functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, $x\in \Bbb{R}$, I want to show that for some $K\geq 0$, $$|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|\leq K|x-y|$$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb{R}$. And furthermore I want to show that $$|f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq K(1+|x|)$$

Clearly $$\begin{align}|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|&=\frac{1}{2}|x-y|+\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1+y^2}\right|\end{align}$$ but I don't see how I can bound $\left|\sqrt{1+x^2}-\sqrt{1+y^2}\right|$ to get something of the form $C|x-y|$.

Also in the second part I'm stuck because $$\begin{align}|f(x)|+|g(x)|&=\frac{1}{2}|x|+|\sqrt{1+x^2}|\\&\leq\frac{1}{2}|x|+1+|x|\\&=1+\frac{3}{2}|x|\end{align}$$ but also here I don't find this $K$ as we wanted. Could someone help me further?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x^2}=1+\frac 12x^2+O(x^4)$

Comment: @Cesareo But I mean then I still get $1/2|x^2-y^2|$?

Comment: Please. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362817/show-polynomial-is-a-lipschitz-function

Comment: $g$ has bounded derivative (prove this!), so by the mean-value theorem, it is Lipschitz.

Comment: @Cesareo that’s only useful for small $x$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo do I need the mean value theorem for your argument, can't I see if $g$ has bounded derivative then it it lipschitz without mean value thoerem?

Comment: For your last question, in general, if $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|$, then $|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+K|x-y|$, so setting $K’=\max(|f(0)|,K)$, we have $|f(x)|\leq K’(1+|x|)$.

Comment: yes you need the mean-value theorem. That is **THE** link between information about derivatives to information about the function. Try to prove Lipschitzness otherwise; you’ll either get stuck or give a wrong proof.

Comment: @peek-a-boo ah perfect thanks a lot!

Comment: @peek-a-boo could you explain how to get from $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|$ to $|f(x)|\leq |f(0)|+K|x-y|$

Comment: Reverse triangle inequality, and sorry I should have set $y=0$, thats a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give a way which does not involves derivatives. Let me use the notation $\langle x\rangle = \sqrt{1+|x|^2}$ and notice that $|x| = \sqrt{|x|^2} \leq \langle x\rangle$, then
$$
|\langle x\rangle - \langle y\rangle|^2 - |x-y|^2 = 2 \left(1+ x\cdot\,y - \langle x\rangle\,\langle y\rangle\right).
$$
Since $|1+x\cdot y|^2 \leq 1 + |x|^2\,|y|^2 + 2\,|x|\,|y| \leq \langle x\rangle^2\,\langle y\rangle^2$, one deduces that
$$
1+ x\cdot\,y - \langle x\rangle\,\langle y\rangle \leq |1+ x\cdot\,y| - \langle x\rangle\,\langle y\rangle \leq 0,
$$
and so from the first equation
$$
|\langle x\rangle - \langle y\rangle| \leq |x-y|.
$$

---

- For the second part, since $1<3/2$, you get $1 + \frac{3}{2}\,|x| \leq \frac{3}{2} (1+|x|)$ ...
- Of course one can also treat the first part with derivatives, notice that $\nabla \langle x\rangle = \frac{x}{\langle x\rangle} =: u(x)$ with $|u|\leq 1$ and so the fundamental theorem of calculus yields
  $$
  \langle x\rangle - \langle y\rangle = (x-y)\cdot\int_0^1 u((1-t)x+ty)\,\mathrm d t
  $$
  which implies
  $$
  |\langle x\rangle - \langle y\rangle| \leq |x-y|\int_0^1 1\,\mathrm d t = |x-y|.
  $$